# window.location in a tabbed website

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, window.location

I'm dealing with a website that uses tabs. The outer tab, is facebook.com. The inner tab is a facebook application.

When I run the following function:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    // to show it in an alert window
    alert(window.location);

    // to store it in a variable
    var loc = window.location;
});
```

The returned value is the url of the inner tab, the host. Is there a way to produce the url of the outer tab using a JQuery function?

Comment: Have you tried `window.top.location`?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're looking for `parent`:

```
window.parent.location;
```

Comment: This is an issue of cross site scripting and this isn't possible.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your page is displayed using Iframes? In that case, you cannot do anything with the parent due to Same Origin Policy restriction. More info can be found on: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy.

If inner and outer tab are on same domain, use:

```
    var parentLoc = parent.location;
```

**Please note** that above JavaScript statement won't work in case page url is for instance 'blah.facebook.com' and the facebook application is load from 'foo.facebook.com'.

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue of cross site scripting and this isn't possible.

"Domains, protocols and ports must match."